# MySQL query: Join tables and display records as comma separated string in a single row

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Suppose I have the following two tables in my MySQL database:

```
Table 1:: EMP: EmpID, EmpName
eg. (1, 'John'), (2,'Alex'),(3,'Tom')

Table 2:: Team: TeamID, ManagerID, MemberID
eg. record1: (Team1, 1, 2), record2: (Team1, 1, 3)
```

so there is a team with id team1, John is the manager and Alex and Tom are its members.

I want to display the records of the Team table on the screen in the following manner

```
| Team  | Manager | Members   |
| team1 | John    | Alex, Tom |
```

What should be SQL query which will join the above two tables and return me the names of the members when based on the memberIDs.

Also the result will be displayed as 1 row containing all the team members separated by a comma.

If there is a better way of designing these two tables then please suggest that also. It will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to use **[`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/)**. `GROUP_CONCAT()` function is used to concatenate column values into a single string. It is very useful if you would otherwise perform a lookup of many row and then concatenate them on the client end.

```
SELECT  b.TeamID as TeamName, 
        a.EmpName as Manager,
        GROUP_CONCAT(c.EmpName) Members
FROM    Emp a
            INNER JOIN Team b
                ON a.EmpID = b.ManagerID
            INNER JOIN  Emp c
                ON b.MemberID = c.EmpID
GROUP BY b.TeamID, a.EmpName
```

You can also change the separator, and the ordering

```
GROUP_CONCAT( c.EmpName SEPARATOR '-' ),...
GROUP_CONCAT( c.EmpName ORDER BY c.EmpName DESC ),...
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61107/4)

Comment: Do you know if there's an equivalent 'group_concat' function in SQL Server? I'm now wondering if I've always done this the long way!

Comment: @Michael No, but you can simulate it. [Click this LINK](http://anthony-yio.blogspot.com/2007/12/mssql-groupconcat.html)

Comment: @Michael Here's [SQLFiddle Demo for MSSQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/001bf/1) for you. Hoe this helps you.

Comment: @Michael glad you asked. I was also wondering how to do this in DBs like Oracle, DB2?

Comment: @JohnWoo Thanks for the information. GROUP_CONCAT() has made life easy!

Comment: @JohnWoo Ah, goodo. I've got a function on the server for it but seeing it up there for MySQL Server made me second guess myself

Comment: @Gaurav [Here's Oracle Version of GROUP_CONCAT](http://halisway.blogspot.com/2006/08/oracle-groupconcat-updated-again.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using [GROUP_CONCAT(expr)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) you can try something like

> This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL
>   values from a group. It returns NULL if there are no non-NULL values.
>   The default separator between values in a group is comma (“,”).

```
SELECT  t.TeamID Team,
        m.EmpName manager,
        GROUP_CONCAT(mem.EmpName) Members
FROM    Team t INNER JOIN
        Emp m   ON  t.ManagerID = m.EmpID INNER JOIN
        Emp mem ON  t.MemberID = mem.EmpID
GROUP BY    t.TeamID Team,
            m.EmpName
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the `EMP` table twice and use `group_concat` to list the members seperately.

```
select TeamID as Team, 
       e2.EmpName as Manager,
       group_concat(e1.EmpName) as Members
from Team t
left outer join EMP e1 on t.MemberID = e1.EmpID
left outer join EMP e2 on t.ManagerID = e2.EmpID
group by TeamID
```

If you use a `left outer join` then you will get results even if there is no manager or members for a team. If you only want teams with members and manager you can use `inner join`.

Answer (score -1):

*Define a view called vTeam with this definition:*

> SELECT     dbo.Team.TeamID, dbo.EMP.EmpName AS Manager, EMP_1.EmpName
>   AS Member, EMP_1.EmpID AS MemberID, dbo.EMP.EmpID AS ManagerID FROM
>   dbo.EMP AS EMP_1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN
>                         dbo.Team ON EMP_1.EmpID = dbo.Team.MemberID LEFT OUTER JOIN
>                         dbo.EMP ON dbo.Team.ManagerID = dbo.EMP.EmpID

*This query will give you your result:*

> SELECT TeamID, Manager, MemberList = STUFF((
>       SELECT ',' + Member FROM vTeam as xx
>       WHERE xx.TeamID = x.TeamID and x.Manager = xx.Manager
>       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') FROM dbo.vTeam AS x GROUP BY TeamID,Manager;

Team1   John    Alex,Tom
Team2   Alex    John,Alex,Tom